# ¿por qué Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.?

Tags: sql-server

¿porque me sale error de: *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string*? esto cuando convierto la fecha a `CAST(DESCRIPCION AS DATE)` si aparentemente sin usar el `CAST` o `CONVERT` el formato de fecha está correcto.

Consulta:

```
DECLARE @TMP TABLE (
        ID INT,
        OBJ_ID INT,
        DESCRIPCION  VARCHAR(250)
        )

INSERT INTO @TMP (ID, OBJ_ID, DESCRIPCION)
VALUES
(1, 223341, 'Base: base 9546.xlsx Obs: 44  FECHA RA: (12/07/2017) BASE: BASE3.E TIPO COSECHA: BAS'),
(2, 223342, 'Base: base 957.xlsx Obs: 12  FECHA RAD: (13/07/2017) BASE: BASE3.E TIPO COSECHA: BAS'),
(3, 223343, 'Base: base 9353.xlsx Obs: 89  FECHA RAD: (07/07/2017) BASE: BASE3.E TIPO COSECHA: BAS'),
(4, 223344, 'Base: base 9250.xlsx Obs: 89  FECHA RAD: (4/07/2017) BASE: BASE2.E TIPO COSECHA: BAS'),
(4, 223344, 'Base: base 9510.xlsx Obs: 34  FECHA RAD: 9/07/2017 BASE: BASE2.E TIPO COSECHA: BAS')


SELECT 
        ID,
        OBJ_ID,
        DESCRIPCION,
        cast(CASE 
                WHEN DESCRIPCION LIKE 'Base:%(%'
                        THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(DESCRIPCION, CHARINDEX('(', DESCRIPCION, 0) + 1, 10), ')', ''), ' ', '')
                ELSE NULL
                END as date) AS FECHA
FROM @TMP

--WHERE DESCRIPCION BETWEEN '20170710' AND '20170715'
```

Objetivo: usar la string del campo `DESCRIPCION` para filtro como fechas `BETWEEN '' AND ''`
ya probé:

```
CAST(campo as DATE)

CAST(campo as DATETIME)

CONVERT(DATE, campo, 102)

CONVERT(DATETIME, campo, 102)

CONVERT(DATE, campo, 103)

CONVERT(DATETIME, campo, 103)
```

Comment: prueba intercambiar el mes y la fecha, osea 07/12/2017 o 2017/07/12  que es el formato estandar de fecha en SQL

Comment: Intercambiarlo? donde en la tabla de la base de datos? imposible, en la clausula where? no es posible, el aplicativo que usará esta vista solo los toma en '20170101'

Comment: `CONVERT(DATE,expresion,103)` me funciona ok

Comment: Si, convierte, pero no filtra, habilita el `WHERE DESCRIPCION BETWEEN '20170710' AND '20170715'` y los registros son "0", eso en la tabla de prueba, en la real arroja error

Comment: @Vulpex, es que tienes  repetir el mismo `CAST` (con todo el `CASE`completo)  del `SELECT` para el `WHERE`.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, Si, ya lo había probado y aunque en la teoría funciona en la práctica no, osea en la base de datos real no funciona, arroja el %$& error, lo que hice para solucionarlo temporalmente fue invertir manualmente  las fechas lo pasé de `20170101` a `01012017` pero aun me queda la intriga de que es lo que causa este error.